# how to position checkboxes around the page using CSS (checkbox value is populated from database)

Tags: php, css, checkbox, input, label

**Situation**

i am an absolute beginner in CSS therefore i am having problems and would like your help. 
i have created a list of checkboxes, however the values of the checkboxes are populated using the values that are stored in mysql database. 
The php code for the checkbox looks like this:

```
<?php

require("user_connection.php");


$q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `campus`");
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="car" 
            value="'.$line['room'].'">'.$line['room'].'</br>';
   }

?>


</br>
</br>



<?php
$q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `campus_two`");
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="car" 
            value="'.$line['room'].'">'.$line['room'].'</br>';
   }

?>


<div id="next"><input type="submit" name="next" Value="next"/></div>
</form>
```

**The problem**

i just want to be able to position the checkbox around the middle of my website. there seems to be tons of tutorials online on how to do that easily using CSS, however all those tutorials have checkbox values embedded into html rather than dynamically generated using database like mine.

currently my CSS looks like this

```
label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    right: 700px;
}
input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    right: 700px;
}
```

now this works fine on a normal checkbox with values embedded into html, but my checkboxes are generated using values from database. i want to be able to position the checkboxes as i want in my website, do you guys know how i can solve this issue?

Comment: We need to see how you WANT this to look...otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: i don't want it to look like anything, i just want it as it is, however i would like to be able to position it around the middle of my site

Comment: Your core assumption for this question is wrong. Your database is generating static HTML that you can check out by viewing the source of the page. There is no difference between static checkboxes and dynamically generated checks.  If your CSS works for your static HTML you're generating the HTML in the wrong way. Your code looks like it would overlap all the elements at a certain position on your screen.

Comment: thankyou! that actually helped more than i thought it would

Answer (score 0):

Don't over think it. PHP is creating html you do that here.

```
<div id="next"><input type="submit" name="next" Value="next"/></div>
```

and

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="car" value="'.$line['room'].'">'.$line['room'].'</br>';
```

The second being dynamically created. Even though that is dynamically created with PHP once the page is rendered you have a page to work with using CSS and even JS.

Let say you want to add class `big-btn` easy enough in the php just do this

```
<div id="next" class="big-btn"><input type="submit" name="next" Value="next"/></div>
```

In your stylesheet

```
.big-btn{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

CSS will make that a bigger button.

Overall though that was simple. You can do that with HTML. Server-side rendering like php is even more powerful in the sense that you could query a data base to build your input like you have here:

```
<?php
    $q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `campus_two`");
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="car" 
        value="'.$line['room'].'">'.$line['room'].'</br>';
    }
?>
```

In this case you could have 1 input or 80 just depends on what is returned but it will be rendered to HTML that can be styled all the same. The other advantage is that you can set flags in the DB and conditionally add classes or ids to really make a dynamic page but once it is rendered (outside of JS) the page is static HTML.